# Conditional comments don't work

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have this code with conditional comments for IE7 and IE8:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="css/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link href="css/ie8fix.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <link href="css/ie7fix.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
```

Stylesheets in conditional comments are not working. I tested this in IE Tester.

Comment: Does your CSS links are correct? Your comments looks fine.

Comment: Wait a sec... Remove the "e" from the end of "lte"

Comment: Remove 'e' didn't help.

Comment: Hmmm... I had a buddy that had a site where that fixed it once for some reason... Even though it shouldn't have! Had to try though... I'm not sure.

Comment: Forget about IETester and use real IE browsers. IETester is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Microsost doesnt support Conditional comments any more. I was kind of stuck myself for a while, so I wrote an an article about it:

http://www.yofiel.com/writing/essays/microsoft-s-exit-strategy

Answer (score 0):

IETester is based on an unsupported hack that has incorrect behaviors in some cases. Have you tried testing in a real browser? Microsoft provides the VMs for free at http://modern.ie.